# What benefit do I get when I use Breeze JS with MS MVC pattern?

Tags: breeze

I need some help in understanding the benefit of using Breeze JS in a Visual Studio MVC project.
With MVC, using razor, I can bind my model properties to controls on the page and have any changes user makes sent back to the server without me writing any code. So, I am not really understanding if in this situation use of Breeze can be beneficial.
Certainly, I am not looking at the whole picture. And that is the reason I am asking this question here. Can anyone explain.
TIA.
kr

Answer (score 0):

breeze is very helpful when you use ORM like NH\EF (also good for nosql and mongo)
if you do stuff like TPT\TPH and circular ref data it's hard to serialize by yourself
breeze takes care of that part for you
you can get your entities on the client side and keep change tracking
also no need to write sql\sp\functions to query data you can do all that on the client side
breeze supports client side cache with ease
breeze also works great with angularjs and knockout, if you bind data to the scope and then use breeze manager to delete or add more data no need to push or splice it breeze does that for you

breeze can do so much more so please check out the docs and features and find out what breeze can do for your project

Answer (score 0):

I am using MVC Pattern and breeze will help us to integrate our typeScript interface generated from T4Ts taking the advantage of have strongly typed entities.

```
 export interface Library extends breeze.Entity {
    Category: string;
    Name: string;
}

var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('api/library');

var query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
    .from("Library");

manager.executeQuery(query).then(data => {   
    var employees = <Library []>data.results;
}).fail(e => {
    alert(e);  
});
```